# Parsing a file in c and copy only specific info to another file

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to parse a file to get rid of the "unnecessary" information (white space, comments (`#` marks comments), etc.) and I know I need to use a combination of `fgets` and `strtok` but I'm not entirely sure how to do this when I need bits and pieces of each line.

**Example:**

Lets say there is one line in a text file I need to parse and it is -

```
    (\t) foo  54  232  574   #random comment
```

and I want it to be structured as -

```
foo 54 232 574
```

How would I go about structuring my `fgets` and `strtok` functions to properly parse lines like this?

Comment: What attempts at writing code have you made so far?

Comment: I first wanted to make sure i was properly reading all of the lines so what i have right now is:
while(!feof(file)){
char str[256];
fgets(str, 256, file);
fprinf(file2, "%s", str);
}
but im not sure if i can use multiple delimiters in strtok or if I'm going about this the wrong way

Comment: Must it be in C? As much as I love C, if you could use Perl, this task would be easier. (Not to say you can't do it in C, you absolutely can, just recommending an alternative tool for the job.)

Comment: yeah it must be in C, thanks for the recommendation though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It reads from stdin and writes to stdout. I noticed you assumed no lines were longer than 256, I made the same assumption here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
        char buf[256];
        while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
                char *hash = strchr(buf, '#');
                if(hash) *hash = 0; // terminate at the '#'

                char *word = strtok(buf, " \t\n");
                int count = 0;
                while(word) {
                        printf("%s%s", count++ ? " " : "", word);
                        word = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
                }
                if(count) {
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

---

Update this is what this code does on your input:

```
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~/junk] crb% a.out < i > o
[Charlies-MacBook-Pro:~/junk] crb% cat o
//This is a sample file I just made to use
.text
main:
la $s0, Var1
lw $s0, 0($s0)
exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
.data
Var1: .word 32
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I'm gonna try it out and see how it works

Comment: This worked well for removing the comments but didnt handle white space or \t properly, thanks though.

Comment: It worked for me on your test case. Are you sure you copied it right? What did it produce that didn't seem right?

Comment: I used a file a little more in depth than my test case, whats the best way to post it up here?

Comment: Put it in pastebin.com and tell me the line you think it got wrong.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tAp8wmYH - sorry after writing this out I realized I was a little vague on what I was trying to do

Comment: What is it you are trying to do then?

Comment: I demonstrate it on the pastebin at the bottom

Comment: That's odd, I don't get the output that you say I get at all. Maybe post your code. Compile just my code above, and run it like this: progname < infile > outfile. See the edit above for what that code does on your input.

Comment: Took another look at the code and figured out what I was doing wrong thanks!!

Comment: But do you mind clarifying how you are using the ternary operator in the printf? Those have always confused me a little

Comment: If count is greater than one, it prints a space before the word. If count is zero, it doesn't print anything. "" is "nothing".

Comment: hey, i changed it so that I remove the $ symbol as well however it is leaving a space instead of "", any quick recommendation on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it'd be easily done using regex.
So even if you can't use perl or something similar, you might want to give C's regex libraries a try.

You'd essentially use something like:

```
s/\s\+\(.*\)#.*/\1/
```

(This is the sed equivalent of what you're trying to, I'll update with the actual C code when I get time later today)

(I'm assuming you want to strip leading whitespaces and trailing commented here)

The equivalent in PCRE:

```
\s+(.*)#.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hWwvoSvj63PO5vbx)